# Is losing wudu during the prayer, and then continuing the prayer haraam?

Tags: halal-haram, salat

Salam alaykum  brothers, today when I was at the mosque, I lost my wudu during the prayer (2nd rakaat, while reciting Surah Al-Fatiha if I remember correctly), after that I was too embarrassed to just leave, I finished the surah contemplating whether I should stop and leave, I did rukoo partially thinking that I'd still get hasanat for doing it, and I did prostrations also partially thinking that I would get hasanat, I was doing sujood and then feared that what I'm doing is sinful, so I stood and left my salat without Salam. I say partially because the main reason was that I was too embarrassed to leave and I also showed little or no khushu, but Allah knows best. Also, my prayer was sunnah, does that change anything?

Comment: Why should something natural as losing wudu' be haram? It is actually sinful to intentionally pray without wudu'. You should leave the prayer if possible and try to get tahrah again and if possible re-join the congregation.

Answer (score 0):

Bro just being fearful is what saves you from any punishment for what you did.
If you were deciding from your side, like if you were certain and self-righteous, then yes you will have punishment. But not because you farted, but because you weren't mutaki

Answer (score 0):

AoA,
If you break wudu while praying, you should complete wudu again.It also matters what you were thinking. If you were too lazy, that leads to punishment.
Hope this helped!
-Amber